# Javascript : Issue in calculating dates

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do the following

a) Get the number of ms passed from 01/01/1970 till now

b) Convert `a)` to number of days

c) Then add `b)` to 01/01/1970

d) I expected `d)` to be today

But the result is not right.

**Today is Dec 01, 2017
From the above code snippet I get Nov 29, 2017**

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to get the correct value ?

**Code snippet**

```
const a = new Date();
console.log('a ==> '+ a);


const b = a.getTime();
console.log('b ==> '+ b);

const c = b/86400000;
console.log('c ==> '+ c);

const d = Math.floor(c);
console.log('d ==> '+ d);

const e = new Date(1970);
e.setDate(d);
console.log('e ==> '+e);
```

**Console.log**

[image]

*EDIT:*

**I updated my code snippet based on comments.
This code snippet below works but I would like to know whether there is something wrong in this snippet. Can some one eyeball this and let me know of a use case where this can go wrong ?**

```
const a = new Date();
console.log('a ==> '+ a);


const b = a.getTime();
console.log('b ==> '+ b);

const c = b/86400000;
console.log('c ==> '+ c);

const d = Math.round(c)+1;
console.log('d ==> '+ d);

const e = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log('e before setting up ==>'+e);
e.setDate(d);
console.log('e ==> '+e);
```

[image]

Comment: I guess it's because of `Math.floor`. It makes the rounding to previous complete day (because today isn't complete). The `new Date(1970)` is "1970 seconds since 1/1/1970 GMT+0", doesn't make sense. And finally, you need to account for timezone. This is what breaks the logic when you do `new Date`.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the number of days because 0 will be the previous month and 1 will be Jan 1, but you are working out days from Jan 1. So you need to add that 1 back on. And as for the second day needing to be added (i.e. 17502) I'm not too sure!

Comment: So you're trying to get today's date? There are easier ways to do that. ;)  What is you really want to do?

Comment: @Seanonymous Basically I would like to store today's date as a number which can then be stored in sqllite db. Also storing a date as number allows me to do sort operations. The database is sqllite db and it does not have a date datatype but only text (which is why I am storing the date as number)

Comment: `a` is set in local timezone, `e` is set in UTC+0. Perhaps not in this particular case, but it generally can cause discrepancies. To compensate, please use [`Date#getTimezoneOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset).

Comment: yeah I think the extra day must have been a timezone thing, because you are now setting `e` to be midnight in local time, instead of +11 hours

Answer (score 0):

I think you were better off with the Math.floor, so long as you're accounting for the timezone offset on both ends.

```
const a = new Date();
console.log('a ==> '+ a);

const b = a.getTime() + a.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log( 'b ==> '+ b );

const c = Math.floor( b / 86400000 );
console.log( 'c ==> '+ c );

const e = new Date( c * 86400000 - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() );

console.log( 'e ==> '+e );
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) that you are using is adding the local time zone offset:

> Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument,
>   **the specified arguments represent local time**. If UTC is desired,
>   use `new Date(Date.UTC(...))` with the same arguments.

```js
console.log( d1 = new Date(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), +d1 ) // "1970-01-01T05:00:00.000Z" 18000000 - time zone offset in milliseconds

console.log( d2 = new Date(0)                     , +d2 ) // "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" 0 - no time zone offset
```

The `new Date()`, `new Date(value)`, and some cases of `new Date(dateString)` constructors don't.

```js
var date1 = new Date
console.log( date1, date1 + '' )   // "2017-12-02T01:03:19.967Z" "Fri Dec 01 2017 20:13:21 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" - local date and time

var days = date1 / 864e5 | 0
console.log( days  )               // 17502

var date2 = new Date( days * 864e5 )
console.log( date2, date2 + '' )   // "2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z" "Fri Dec 01 2017 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
```